# visual studio c++ : a value of type "const wchar_t *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "TCHAR *"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, text

I am using a visual studio 2019. I am also using Charles Petzold - Programming Windows - 5th Ed, page 291. How do I fix this error on **TEXT**?

```
struct {
    int     iStyle;
    TCHAR*  szText;
} 

button[] = { 
    BS_PUSHBUTTON,      TEXT ("PUSHBUTTON"),
    BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,   TEXT ("DEFPUSHBUTTON"),
    BS_CHECKBOX,        TEXT ("CHECKBOX"),
    BS_AUTOCHECKBOX,    TEXT ("AUTOCHECKBOX"),
    BS_RADIOBUTTON,     TEXT ("RADIOBUTTON"),
    BS_3STATE,          TEXT ("3STATE"),
    BS_AUTO3STATE,      TEXT ("AUTO3STATE"),
    BS_GROUPBOX,        TEXT ("GROUPBOX"),
    BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON, TEXT ("AUTORADIO"),
    BS_OWNERDRAW,       TEXT ("OWNERDRAW") 
};
```

Comment: Are you writing this in C++? (That is to say, using a C++ compiler), that book is a C book I believe

Comment: Try making it a const pointer. Based on the error message

Comment: struct {
    int     iStyle;
    const TCHAR*  szText;
}

Answer (score 1):

String literals are `const` data, of type `const <char>[N]`, which decays to `const <char> *`.  Where `<char>` is `char`, `wchar_t`, `char16_t`, or `char32_t`, depending on the type prefix in front of the literal (`L` for `wchar_t`, `u` for `char16_t`, `U` for `char32_t`, and `u8` for `char`/`char8_t`).  If no prefix is specified, `char` is used.

When `UNICODE` is defined, `TCHAR` is an alias for `wchar_t`, and `TEXT()` places an `L` prefix in front of the specified literal.  If `UNICODE` is not defined, `TCHAR` is an alias for `char`, and `TEXT()` omits the prefix.

So, calling `TEXT()` on a string literal effectively produces a `const TCHAR[N]`, which then decays to `const TCHAR *`.

Your struct contains a pointer to a non-const `TCHAR`.  You can't initialize a "pointer to non-const" (`TCHAR*`) with a "pointer to const" (`const TCHAR*`) in C++11 and later (you can in C, and pre-2011 C++).  So, you need to change your `szText` to be a pointer to a `const TCHAR`, eg:

```
struct {
    int          iStyle;
    const TCHAR* szText;
}
```

Or:

```
struct {
    int           iStyle;
    TCHAR const * szText;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `LPCTSTR` alias, which is an alias for `const TCHAR*`, eg:

```
struct {
    int      iStyle;
    LPCTSTR  szText;
}
```